# Does the Push Notification Service work on an iPod Touch?

Tags: iphone, ipod-touch

Does the Push Notification Service work on an iPod Touch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iPod touch does support push notifications.  There is something to know though.

from the developer portal

[What Are Push Notifications?](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/WhatAreRemoteNotif/WhatAreRemoteNotif.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH102-SW1)

> Important: WiFi is used for push
>   notifications only if there is no
>   cellular connection or if the device
>   is an iPod touch. To receive
>   notifications via Wi-Fi, the device’s
>   display must be on (that is, it cannot
>   be sleeping) or it must be plugged in.

This applies to both the iPhone and the iPod touch.

Hope that helps.

chris.

Answer (score 4):

Your ipod must connected to a wireless network and be running software verion 3.0 or higher to work with Push notifications.

Answer (score 0):

You need iPhone OS 3.0